# Is there any difference implied when calling an argument a "switch" or a "flag"?

Tags: arguments, terminology

Suppose I'm writing a routine that can have one of two different behaviors. I could pass it a boolean/logical argument that tells my routine which of the two behaviors to choose.

In general, is it more accurate to call that argument a "switch" or a "flag", or something else? Is there a consensus, and if so, is there any implied difference between these terms?

I've heard these terms used interchangeably, but recently somebody said that while a "switch" selects one of two behaviors, a "flag" selects one of multiple behaviors.

Comment: "recently somebody said that while a "switch" selects one of two behaviors, a "flag" selects one of multiple behaviors" I would argue the exact opposite. A flag is usually binary, whereas a switch usually has 2+ cases. In the end, it doesn't matter what you call it. Anyone who can't get over you using either word for your case is not worth working with.

Comment: I would almost equate this to them arguing over calling it a function "argument" vs. "parameter".

Comment: @mhodges l think their rationale was that the term “switch” evokes a power switch that can be either switched on or switched off. However, that usage conflicts with the “switch” construct that is used in many programming languages and fits your terminology.

Comment: Ah, I see. I would have never thought of a "power switch" in the context of anything to do with programming. Seems to be context-dependent and primarily opinion-based. Not sure if it's on-topic. Speaking of opinions, mine is that you should call it a "flag" (even if it is non-binary). The term `switch` is too tightly coupled (connotatively) to the switch programming construct.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days of computers before they had compilers they use to enter the values into the computers using manual switches with each switch representing a single bit. Now since typical processors do not have a data type for a single bit, they are typically represented using an entire byte, e.g. in C `unsigned char` is common. When processing Boolean values one does not have to take into account their position in the value. Also a series of operations with bool values results in a single bool value.

To the best of my knowledge the term flag comes from the flag registers in computers where each flag representing one bit. However, with flags they are grouped into sizes based on the processor register size.

Another common use for flag is with enumeration types. When processing enum flag values one does have to take into account their position in the value. Also a series of operations with enum flag values results in a enum flag value and not a single bool value.

> Suppose I'm writing a routine that can have one of two different
>   behaviors. In general, is it more accurate to call that argument a
>   "switch" or a "flag", or something else?

I would not call it a switch as that is old terminology and I would definitely not call it a flag. I would call it a `bool`.

Comment: Calling it a `bool` is language dependent because it is the name of a (usually) primitive boolean data type for a particular language (Java calls it a `boolean`, Fortran calls it a `logical`...). I’m looking for a language-independent term for that *kind* of argument, regardless of its data type/representation in a particular language or program. I could use any pair of integers (0 and 1, or 0 and -1, or 999 and -50), a char (a and b, or t and f, or p and q), or a boolean—but what is the best colloquial term for this kind of argument along the lines of calling a variable a flag or a switch?